# a unitary relation between a matrix and its transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $F$ be a field, $E/F$ is a quadratic extension. The notions "Hermitian matrix, unitary matrix" make sense for $E/F$. In fact, a matrix $A$ is called Hermitian if $A=\bar A^T$. Given a Hermitian matrix $\beta\in GL_n(E)$, one can define a unitary group $U_\beta=\{g\in GL_n(E):g\beta \bar g^T=\beta\}$.

The question is: given a $n\times n$ matrix $A$ with entries in $E$, is it true that there are $U,V\in U_\beta$ such that $A=UA^T V$, where $A^T$ is the transpose of $A$? (At least when $\beta=1_n$).

If $F$ is the real field, and $E$ is the complex field, this is true by a paper of William Gordan "a unitary relation between a matrix and its transpose", Canadian Math.Bull.1970, page 279-280. Is this true for a general field $F$? This result is referred in a paper by Garcia and Tener (link: http://arxiv.org/pdf/0908.2107.pdf).

A similar question is: Let $F$ be a general field. Is it true that every $A\in M_{n\times n}(F)$ similar to its transpose? The answer yes. This is also referred by the above paper.

A stronger question is: Is it true that there is a unitary matrix $U$ such that $A=UA^T\bar U^T$ (if $A$ satisfies this condition, $A$ is called UET(unitarily equivalent to its transpose) in the literature)? The answer is no, even when $F=\textbf{R},E=\textbf{C}$. The above paper by Garcia and Tener give a condition for a matrix to be UET in the $\textbf{C}/\textbf{R}$ case.

Comment: It will be extremely helpful if there was a link to this paper in the OP.

Comment: Have you tried going through Gordan's proof, to see whether it extends to the general case? or where it may break down, and suggest a counterexample? Is $A$ supposed to have entries in $F$, $U$ and $V$ in $E$?

Comment: I do not have the paper by Gordan. But in a paper by Garcier and Tener (link: http://arxiv.org/pdf/0908.2107.pdf), the above result is referred.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: Thanks for your suggestion. A is in GLn(E), and U,V also have entries in E. I will check if this is still true over a general base field. But I think, usually in such proof over the complex field, one uses the existence of eigenvalues.